# textarea html tags get converted to plain text

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm using CKEditor to make posts to a site. However, I enter something in which creates HTML tags, but they are returned as plain text:

[Plain-text image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqZdV.png)

I enter them as:
[HTML post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkOHu.png)

I'm using EJS (if it matters) for my view-engine, and the code which shows the posts is:

```
<ul class="main-posts">
          <% for(var i=0; i < posts.length; i++) { %>
            <div class="postbg">
             <li class="li-post"><strong><%= posts[i].pTitle %></strong></li>
             <li class="li-author"><strong>Author:</strong> <%= posts[i].author %></li>
             <li class="li-content"><%= posts[i].content %></li>
           </div>
             <br />
          <% }; %>
        </ul>
```

And my posts function:

```
exports.posts = function(req, res) {
var time = moment().format("hh:mm A MM/DD/YYYY");
new Post({
author: req.body.author,
content: req.body.content,
pTitle: req.body.pTitle,
date: time
}).save(function(err, post){
res.redirect('/');
});
};
```

Comment: Would it be correct to summarize this as "`<%= posts[i].content %>` outputs HTML-encoded content instead of the raw HTML"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is the EJS you're referring to: http://ejs.co/, it looks like you should use `<%- %>` for outputting raw HTML, like this:

```
<ul class="main-posts">
  <% for(var i=0; i < posts.length; i++) { %>
    <div class="postbg">
      <li class="li-post"><strong><%= posts[i].pTitle %></strong></li>
      <li class="li-author"><strong>Author:</strong> <%= posts[i].author %></li>
      <li class="li-content"><%- posts[i].content %></li>
    </div>
    <br />
  <% }; %>
</ul>
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks a ton!